# @ not working on Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Can anybody please let me know that why my keyboard not showing @ symbol while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: Is it an old keyboard? Laptop keyboard? Dirty? Clean? We need more info mate.

Comment: what does it type instead or does it not type anything at all?

Answer (score 6):

Is it showing a double quote instead? e.g. "

Have you got the correct language settings/keyboard layout set up in your operating system? Try changing it from UK English -> US English.

Answer (score 2):

If it turns out to be a defunct keyboard and you have a numberpad on it you can always Hold down Alt, type 064 on the numberpad, **then release Alt**.
Not a long term fix but may get you by for the moment.